# No type hint in webstorm ts(typescript)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have this problem, this is not the first time I have noticed that webstorm does not give any hints about what values can be used, although the type is registered.
`export type IconsNames = Icons.IconNames`
In short, I have a library where there is a type of icons, which in turn takes the type from the namespace (`declare namespace Icons {export type IconNames = {'value'|'value2'}`), this library uses a storybook, if you use this type in it, then it seems to work fine (but also not as we would like, for example, to have hints need to be written in props like ={'value'}, and not ='value' , so if you use the library in a project and use this type, it does not give hints at all, although when you hover the mouse the type is indicated correctly, what should I do?